# T-SQL recursion

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a set of data that looks like below

```
Name  Time   Perc   Group  Mode  Control  Cancelled
A     10:52  10.10   10     0      1         0
B     09:00  10.23   10     1      1         1
C     12:02  12.01   12     0      1         1
D     10:45  12.12   12     1      7         1
E     12:54  12.56   12     1      3         0
F     01:01  13.90   13     0      11        1
G     02:45  13.23   13     1      12        1
H     09:10  13.21   13     1      1         0
```

I need an output like below;

```
Group  Perc   Cancelled
 10    20.33     1
 12    36.69     2
 13    40.34     2
```

What I'm getting was something like;

```
Group  Perc   Cancelled
 10    20.33     5
 12    36.69     5
 13    40.34     5
```

I don't know what to call this, I have something in my mind to call it like CTE?, but I really can't figure it out.

Here's my source;

```
 SELECT Group, SUM(Perc), Cancelled FROM
 (SELECT Group, Perc, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblName WHERE Cancelled=1) AS Cancelled    FROM tblName WHERE 1=1 AND Group>=10)dt
 GROUP BY Group, Cancelled
```

Comment: Are you using a keyword as a column name in your real code? I saw "SELECT Group" and got confused. "GROUP BY Group" is bewildering.

Comment: just now, what i did was i created a #temp table then select'ed all the data first then left join the #temp table.. it does solve the issue, but i feel its a little bit lame..

Answer (score 3):

From your example, you don't need the nested query, any recursion, etc...

```
SELECT
  Group,
  SUM(Perc)        AS total_perc,
  SUM(cancelled)   AS total_cancelled
FROM
  tblName
WHERE
  1=1
  AND Group >= 10
GROUP BY
  Group
```

If you did have some different data, then you might want to use something like...

```
SUM(CASE WHEN cancelled > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)   AS total_cancelled
```

Comment: What's the purpose of having `1=1` in there?

Comment: @goatco - Copied from OPs code.  Guessing it's to make building a dynamic where clause easier.

Comment: my sample was to blame and who made it is no other that me, i forgot to show in the sample that before i can get the cancelled i need to validate the mode and control such as if mode=1 and control=1 then it is cancelled.. so can you please show me how?

Comment: @paulpolo - Do you mean that you don't have a cancelled field, but that *a row should be counted as cancelled if* `mode > 0 AND control > 0`?  *(You said `= 1` in your comment, but in your data you have a row where control = 7, yet you treat that as cancelled?)*